# How to align or resize controls on Form?

Tags: wix, alignment

WixEdit cannot align (to right) controls on form. SharpDevelop doesn't save changes in wxs file. How to do it?

Comment: What about manually editing the underlying WXS file? The tools you mention can have issues, that's life...

Comment: :-)) yes ... Trying to use Sharpdevelop+manual actions ...But 2011 year

Comment: By the way, could you suggest good manual method to align 2 text controls to right, for example how to align fast and exactly labels:                               User: [edit control]                                           Password: [edit control]

Comment: I was always thinking it's all about setting proper X/Y coordinates and Width/Height dimensions. Make sure X+Width of one control equals to X+Width of another one, and both will be aligned to right...

Comment: Hmm.. control boxes will be aligned to right, but text always anchored to left corner of textbox, that is why texts will be aligned to left side.

Answer (score 1):

Set `RightAligned` attribute of [`Control`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_control.htm) element to 'yes'. It will make text in the control right-aligned. Not all controls support this attribute.

Sample code:

```
<Control Type="Text" RightAligned="yes"
         Width="77" Height="17" X="26" Y="126"
         Id="label1" Text="This label has the long text:" />
<Control Type="Text" RightAligned="yes"
         Width="77" Height="17" X="26" Y="150"
         Id="label2" Text="Short:" />
```

Note: *the widths are same*. The text in the label control is displayed flush right.

Comment: @Oleg Usually left-aligned control labels are used. See [Microsoft recommendations on label alignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511279.aspx#labelalignment). If I'm not mistaken, we used right aligned labels, I'll check tomorrow.

Comment: @Oleg Yes, we did use it. I updated the answer with the sample code.